# Swiper.JS combined with PhotoSwipe in React JS

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, image-gallery, photoswipe

There are people who made it, but not in react...

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  centeredSlides: true,
  grabCursor: true,
  effect: "creative",
  creativeEffect: {
    prev: {
      shadow: true,
      translate: ["-30%", 0, -1],
    }, TO BE CONTINUED...
    
  >> The actual code is huge, but this is only for the codepen link
```

- [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/XNpJaX)

The confusing part is how do I combine the elements of these react libraries if they come with just ready-to-use components. There is not that much flexibility as there is in pure HTML. 
Please show me the way to the right direction

Comment: I would suggest to use Fancybox, because it works with Carousel without writing any code